# Postgres query issues

Tags: postgresql

I'm not sure why this structure is not working. This is my first time working with postgres and was hoping someone could help me.

```
SELECT * FROM "friends" WHERE "from" = '1' OR "to" = '1' AND "status" = '1'
```

It returns all values where from where "from" is = 1 and "to" = 1 rather than one or the other where "status" is = 1

I hope that isn't too confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OR operator has lower precedence than AND [[1]](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-syntax.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE). As a result, the expression is evaluated as follows:

```
(
    "from" = '1'
)
OR
(
    "to" = '1'
    AND
    "status" = '1'
)
```

What you probably want instead is:

```
SELECT * FROM "friends" WHERE ("from" = '1' OR "to" = '1') AND "status" = '1'
```